# For a homomorphism $\phi:G\to H$, is the preimage of a coset $aN$ of $H$ is of the form $b\phi^{-1}(N)$, where $b\in \phi^{-1}(a)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Given a homomorphism $\phi:G\to H$, I am not sure if the preimage of a coset $aN$ of $H$ is in the form of $b\phi^{-1}(N)$, where $b\in \phi^{-1}(a)$?

My attempt:

Since $\phi(b\phi^{-1}(N))=\phi(b)N=aN$, $b\phi^{-1}(N)\subset \phi^{-1}(aN)$. Now to any $x\in  \phi^{-1}(aN)=\phi^{-1}(a)\phi^{-1}(N)$, we can express $x$ by $ch$, where $c\in\phi^{-1}(a), h\in\phi^{-1}(N)$.

So $x\in c\phi^{-1}(N)=bb^{-1}c\phi^{-1}(N)$. Since $\phi(b^{-1}c)=a^{-1}a=1\in N$, $b^{-1}c\in \phi^{-1}(N)$, hence $x\in c\phi^{-1}(N)=b\phi^{-1}(N)$. So $\phi^{-1}(aN)\subset b\phi^{-1}(N)$. Therefore $\phi^{-1}(aN)= b\phi^{-1}(N)$.

Am I right?

Comment: Is there some step of the proof that you're not sure about?

Comment: @DanielHast I am just afraid that if I made mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you're right. Well done!

As is customary for a [proof-verification](/questions/tagged/proof-verification) question, a little  more than a yes/no answer is polite. I would like to point out, then, that your current use of paragraphs is slightly strange. You cut through your proof of one side of the set inclusion, which starts directly after your proof of the other, where I believe the paragraph should start.

I can't fault your mathematics but note that $b$ might not be unique, which is to say that there could be some $b'$ with the same property.